# CombineLatest is not taking the latest value in rxjs

Tags: rxjs6, combinelatest

this is the code

```
const timerOne = timer(1000, 4000).pipe(
  map(x=>`1-${x}-${new Date().getSeconds()}`)
)
//timerTwo emits first value at 2s, then once every 4s
const timerTwo = timer(2000, 4000).pipe(
  map(x=>`2-${x}-${new Date().getSeconds()}`)
);
//timerThree emits first value at 3s, then once every 4s
const timerThree = timer(3000, 4000).pipe(
  map(x=>`3-${x}-${new Date().getSeconds()}`)
);

//when one timer emits, emit the latest values from each timer as an array
const combined = combineLatest(timerOne, timerTwo, timerThree);

const subscribe = combined
.pipe(take(5))
.subscribe(
  ([timerValOne, timerValTwo, timerValThree]) => {   
    console.log(
     ` ${timerValOne},
    ${timerValTwo},
     ${timerValThree}`
    );
  }
);
```

this is the definition for combineLatest() in rxjs

> will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least
>   one value.

now from the above defintion, the output should be

```
1-2-56,
2-1-57,
3-0-58
```

instead of

```
1-0-56,
2-0-57,
3-0-58
```

because, we will only get the value of the **timerThree** Observable after 3second by that time the latest value for **timerOne** would be 2 and the latest value for **timerTwo** would be 1, am i missing something, please help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timers will first emit in [1s, 2s, 3s] and will continue at 4s rate.

So the first time when **all streams** will emit is at **3s**.

Next events on [`combineLatest`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/combineLatest/) (when all streams have emitted and any of the streams emit a new event) are: 5s, 6s, 7s ...

Heres an illustration for

```js
const timerOne = timer(100, 400);
const timerTwo = timer(200, 400);
const timerThree = timer(300, 400);
combineLatest(timerOne, timerTwo, timerThree, (...arr)=>arr.join('-'));
```

[image: timer with combineLatest illustration]

And this is a playground for [**combineLatest with timers**](https://thinkrx.io/gist/cca5146802c43c401e4742c7b6e96340)

Hope this helps